# Create type from composed string literal types

Tags: typescript

I have three Typescript types like this:

```
type Mum = {
  stage: "here" | "are" | "some" | "stages";
};

type Dad = {
  stage: "more" | "steps" | "that" | "could" | "happen";
};

type Child = Mum | Dad;
```

and I have a function that consumes `Child`:

```
function myFunc(person: Child): void {
  switch (person.stage) {
    case "here":
    //doThings();
  }
}
```

But I don't want to pass in the entire `Child` type, only the `stage`. How can I change this function signature so that it accepts a `stage` without using `any`, or keeping a manual copy of the string literal about?

```
function myFunc(stage: any): void {
  switch (stage) {
    case "here":
    //doThings();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two things either directly access `stage` from `Child` type or create a `Stage` type ot of your `Child` type

```
type Mum = {
  stage: "here" | "are" | "some" | "stages";
};

type Dad = {
  stage: "more" | "steps" | "that" | "could" | "happen";
};

type Child = Mum | Dad;

function myFunc(stage: Child['stage']): void {
  switch (stage) {
    case "here":
    //doThings();
  }
}

type Stages = Child['stage']

function myFunc2(stage: Stages): void {
  switch (stage) {
    case "here":
    //doThings();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use an index access type to get the type of `stage` in `Child`:

```
function myFunc(stage: Child ['stage']): void {
  switch (stage) {
    case "here":
    //doThings();
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsgrgWygXigbwLACgpQM7ACGA5hAFxQBEAFhAE4SVQA+VhDTrleA9goyyoESEPJQDc2AL6Ss2UJCgARQgBMU6bLmGkKlBDw6DuwCGDHHg1QsE5UAxjzgAbVXZqEwkAHYTps+XBoAGFqAEtXDXgkVhVVAKwAMzhve2Awnm8oBBAAMRT7AAodcihQiPUAbQByEuqAXQBKCgA3HjD1TBx8AHcw4HtqKGKiUkbNbtx7QjxoGnpGMi1cKAB6VdUeABVw72I8QsbZXClpIA)